# How to restrict domain user access to FsX folders in a EC2 Windows Environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-fsx

Background: A Windows domain set up in AWS EC2 with member servers. We use our own AD which is also hoted in the same VPC. An FsX share has been created that is mounted on all Windows servers that are part of the domain. The FsX share mounts fine. However, by default it appears that any authenticated user on the domain has read/write access to the FsX share.

We are struggling with limiting read/write access to certain folders in the share to only designated users.

AWS docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/limit-access-file-folder.html say the following:

> Every Amazon FSx file system comes with a default Windows file share
> called share. The Windows ACLs for this shared folder are configured
> **to allow read/write access to domain users**. They also allow full
> control to the delegated administrators group in your Active Directory
> that is delegated to perform administrative actions on your file
> systems. If you're integrating your file system with AWS Managed
> Microsoft AD, this group is AWS Delegated FSx Administrators. If
> you're integrating your file system with your self-managed Microsoft
> AD setup, this group can be Domain Admins. Or it can be a custom
> delegated administrators group that you specified when creating the
> file system. To change the ACLs, you can map the share as a user that
> is a member of the delegated administrators group.

Is it possible to override this default behavior and if so, how?

We mount the file share on V: drive and want that V:\user1 folder should only have RW for user1@domain.com an V:\user2 should likewise be limited to user2@domain.com

From the Folder Properties security it does not permit removal of the All Users permission as it is inheriting it from someother perm that was set up during creation of the FsX.

Answer (score 0):

No answer yet. aws FSx doesnt support disabling inheritance on main share folder, so we will not be able to achieve to restrict access to particular folder for particular user, as all AD users are part of Authenticated users group which we cant remove, if we deny it, we will not be able to access the folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).